# how to return components within paths? (syntax errors)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are syntax errors in the `return` of the `components` so the app doesn't work (not render in the browser), how to `return` `components` within `paths`?
the problem is here (return App):

```
<Route exact path='/' component={()=>{    return  <Addroom {
    <button onClick={add=this.create}>Create</button>}/>}}/>


<Route exact path='/room' component={()=>{this.state.roomsList.map((element, key) => {
          return (
            <Room
              id={key + 1}
              key={key}
              r={element.room}
              rt={element.roomType}
              ct={element.colorType}
              sr={element.boxColor}
            />
          );
        })}}/>
```

I share all the components to help understanding:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
// import './App.css';
import Addroom from "./components/Addroom.js";
import Room from "./components/Room.js";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    roomsList: []
  };

  create = r => {
    this.setState({
      roomsList: [...this.state.roomsList, r],
      
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="backGroundMain" style={{backgroundColor: "lightseagreen", height: "600px", width: "850px"}}>
        <h1 style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "40px", width: "270px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px", margin: "15px"}} >My Smart House</h1>

<Router>

 <div className="row">

   <div className="col-6"><Link to='/room'>My Rooms</Link></div>
   <div className="col-6"><Link to='/'>Create Room</Link></div>

   </div>

<Switch>
        
<Route exact path='/' component={()=>{    return  <Addroom {
      
       <button style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "20px", width: "60px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px"}} onClick={add=this.create}>Create</button>}/>}}/>


<Route exact path='/room' component={()=>{this.state.roomsList.map((element, key) => {
          return (
            <Room
              id={key + 1}
              key={key}
              r={element.room}
              rt={element.roomType}
              ct={element.colorType}
              sr={element.boxColor}
            />
          );
        })}}/>

</Switch>
</Router>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Room.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Room extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { id, r, rt, ct, sr } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="Box" style={{backgroundColor: sr, height: "170px", width: "170px", margin: "30px"}}> 
        <h3>
          Room {id}: {r}{" "}
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Room Type {id}: {rt}
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Room Color {id}: {ct}
        </h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Addroom.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Addroom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      roomNameInputColor: "white",
      roomTypes: ["kitchen", "bathroom", "bedroom"],
      roomSelected: "kitchen",
      colorTypes: ["red", "green", "blue", "teal", "mediumblue", "mediumorchid", "wheat", "Steelblue"],
      colorSelected: "red"
    };
  }


  addRoomName = e => {
    const room = e.target.value;

    let roomNameInputColor = "white";
    if (e.target.value.length >= 5) {
      roomNameInputColor = "green";
    } else {
      roomNameInputColor = "red";
    }

    this.setState({ room, addRoomName: room, roomNameInputColor });
  };

  createRoom = () => {
    this.props.add({
      room: this.state.room,
      roomType: this.state.roomSelected,
      colorType: this.state.colorSelected,
      boxColor: this.state.colorSelected
    });
  };

  createRoomType = () => {
    this.props.addRoomType(this.state.roomSelected);
  };

  createColorType = () => {
    this.props.addColorType(this.state.colorSelected);
  };

  createBoxColor = () => {
    this.props.colorTheBox(this.state.colorSelected);
  };


  setCategory = roomSel => {
    this.setState({ roomSelected: roomSel });
  };

  setColorCategory = colorSel => {
    this.setState({ colorSelected: colorSel });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="backGroundAddRoom" style={{backgroundColor: "mediumaquamarine", height: "93px", width: "200px", margin: "15px"}}>
        {/* //Select Room Type */}
        <select onChange={e => this.setCategory(e.target.value)}>
          {this.state.roomTypes.map((type, key) => (
            <option key={key} value={type}>
              {type}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />

        {/* //Select Room Color */}
        <select onChange={e => this.setColorCategory(e.target.value)}>
          {this.state.colorTypes.map((type, key) => (
            <option key={key} value={type}>
              {type}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />

        <input
          onChange={this.addRoomName}
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.roomNameInputColor }}
          placeholder="Name Your Room"
        />
        <br />

        <button style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "20px", width: "60px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px"}}
         onClick={this.createRoom}>Create</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check a render property of Route `<Route render={() => {}} />`.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state.roomsList.map((element, key) => {
      return (
        <Room
          id={key + 1}
          key={key}
          r={element.room}
          rt={element.roomType}
          ct={element.colorType}
          sr={element.boxColor}
        />
      );
    })
```

Put above map in one single component and then use

```
<Route exact path='/room' component={RoomListComponent}/>
```